# How to create Web Worker in a SvelteKit app on Vercel?

Tags: javascript, web-worker, svelte, vercel, sveltekit

I've created a SvelteKit webapp that works great on my desktop in my local environment. I launch the browser/webserver with:

```
npm run dev -- --open
```

Now I've just deployed to Vercel. Everything works great, except the JavaScript command I use to launch my Web Worker gives a 404 error in the browser console:

```
new Worker('./lib/game/runs_thread.js')
```

Sure enough, if I copy `/lib/game/runs_thread.js` into my browser after my domain name, I get a 404 error. Where is my `runs_thread.js` and how can I launch my Worker?

Answer (score 5):

I think what you need to do is replace

```js
new Worker('./lib/game/runs_thread.js')
```

with

```js
import workerURL from './lib/game/runs_thread.js?url';
//...
new Worker(workerURL)
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to create the `Worker` inside `onMount` otherwise I'd get a 500 error because `Worker` is undefined in Node.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively,

```js
import MyWorker from "./path/to/worker.js?worker"
new MyWorker()
```

From [vite's documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#importing-script-as-a-worker)

Comment: I'm not sure if this works with plain Svelte, but SvelteKit throws an error because `Worker` is undefined during the SSR. I had to use the `?url` pattern to create the `Worker` manually inside `onMount` to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// someComponent.svelte or +page.svelte or +layout.svelte
onMount(async () => { // must be "async" because of the dynamic import. see "await import" below
  if (browser) { // prevent the script from being executed server-side
    if (window.Worker) { // "window" is available because we're in "onMount"
      // Vite dyn import: https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#importing-script-as-a-worker
      const MyWorker = await import('$lib/workers/my_worker.js?worker');
      const myWorker = new MyWorker.default(); 
      myWorker.postMessage('do-this');
      myWorker.onmessage = function (e) {
        console.log(e.data);
      };
    }
  }
})
```

```js
// $lib/workers/my_worker.js
self.onmessage = (e) => {
    if (e.data === 'do-this') {
        doThis();
        postMessage('job-done');
    }
};

function doThis(){
  // doing something
}
```